# How to get the average number of minutes from datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

What I want to do is show the average number of minutes a technician has worked on each ticket, but only where the average is greater than or equal to the overall average minutes per ticket. But you can't use avg on datetime.

I know this is quite wrong, but this is what I'm starting with:

```
select user_firstname + ' ' + user_lastname as technician_name, 
avg(ticket_requestdate - ticket_closeddate) as average_minutes_per_ticket
from hd_users
    join hd_tickets on ticket_requestor_id=user_id
where user_is_technician = '1' 
having avg(ticket_requestdate - ticket_closeddate) >=
        (select avg(ticket_requestdate - ticket_closeddate) from hd_users)
```

Comment: if you provide table structure it makes more sense. It is difficult to find out which field in which table atm.

Answer (score 2):

I would use datediff() with minutes in a subquery

```
datediff(minute,datestart,dateend)
```

then you get the number of minutes as int and then you can do the avg()

or

```
avg(datediff(minute,datestart,dateend))
```

----EDIT ----
I'm guessing a bit since I don't know your table structure, but what about this

```
select user_firstname + ' ' + user_lastname as technician_name, 
avg(Datediff(minute,ticket_requestdate,ticket_closeddate)) as average_minutes_per_ticket
from hd_users
join hd_tickets on ticket_requestor_id=user_id
where user_is_technician = '1' 
GROUP BY user_firstname, user_lastname 
having avg(Datediff(minute,ticket_requestdate,ticket_closeddate)) >=
    (select avg(Datediff(minute,ticket_requestdate,ticket_closeddate)) from hd_users)
```

Comment: [Please use `MINUTE` and not `'m'`. Here's why](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx). Currently this yields an error, and `M` is for month anyway, not minute. I think that demonstrates my point quite handily: lazy shorthand is stupid.

Comment: thanks for the comment and link to your blog, I have updated my answer and will steer clear of shorthand abbreviations from now on @AaronBertrand

Comment: But how do I deal with >= ? I'm getting an error that says that more than one value would be returned, which is not allowed with >=

Comment: @Laura did you not keep the `avg` in your expressions? You should simply replace `ticket_requestdate - ticket_closeddate` with `datediff(minute, ticket_requestdate, ticket_closeddate)` and leave everything else the same. Your current query is backwards anyway - it implies that request date is later than closed date, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I think you were also missing a group by, look at my latest edit @LauraHarmon